# Firebase Setup with PHP CURL

Tags: php, firebase, curl, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Trying to retrieve data from firebase, but getting error.
Please help me for setup this.

My Code is

```
function Process($url){
    $Return = new stdClass;

    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  // remove header 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0); // remove body 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

    if($Return->response = curl_exec($ch)){
        $Return->response = json_decode($Return->response);
    }

    $Return->httpCode   = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $Return->curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $Return->curl_error = curl_error($ch); 

    curl_close($ch); 
    return $Return;
}

$Info = Process('https://project-id.firebaseio.com/users/jack/name.json');
```

but getting response **Unauthorized request.**

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/plain'));` add this

Comment: I try this, my question is how can i set API or access token ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your authorization key into the header section of your curl. 
The server key or token depends on what information you are trying to retrieve from the firebase.

if its personal information about the account you can see the example on this link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth

if you are trying to retrieve information for a certain project then this server key can be found within the project console in firebase.

```
$server_key ='YOUR SERVER KEY';
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
  'Authorization:key='.$server_key
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: I got the server key from settings>Cloud Messaging Tab>Server Key but still Permission denied.

Comment: What information are you trying to grab? Each section has different validation. are you trying to send notification to registered devices?